# When i do composer update some extension errors are showing

Tags: laravel, composer

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for phar-io/manifest 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by phar-io/manifest[1.0.3].
    - phar-io/manifest 1.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.1.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.1.4].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 7.5.13 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.5.13].
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.5.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.1.3].
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

i have tried with somes commands to fix the issue.

1.sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring

2.sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml

after runnig the commands one more time i tried to composer update but same errors are showing

Answer (score 0):

**I have got a command to fix the issue**

run this command with installed  php version

> sudo apt-get install php-gd php-xml php7.1-mbstring

after running this command composer update was done successfully